# $P($partial sums of $\sum X_k$ are bounded$)>0 \to \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k < \infty\ \text{a.s.}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, summation, martingales

From Williams' Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

How is the remark deduced from the proof of $b$? I really don't see it.

Comment: Just curious, why do you seem to be such a fan of this text?

Comment: @Math1000 good question. Well it's the main text we used in probability theory so I just continued from there. I tried Rosenthal, our secondary text, but the order of topics wasn't exactly the same. I should go back to Rosenthal. I think the notation and format is kind of better. Has more exercises and there's a solutions manual. just already got so used to Williams I guess. Thanks for asking ^-^ any particular reason for asking? You got suggestions?

Comment: I just noticed that you tend to copy/paste a lot of passages from the book, and the formatting is easily recognizable. I highly recommend *Adventures in Stochastic Processes* by Resnick if you're looking for another text to consult. The exercises are very interesting :)

Comment: @Math1000 thanks but is that a probability textbook and not a stochastic calculus textbook? If it's a stochastic calculus textbook there may be things I don't know yet from probability. I took stochastic calculus but my prof knew what my class knew or didn't know from probability. So whenever we were missing something from probability, my prof would fill us in.

Comment: It covers probability generating functions, branching processes, Markov chains, renewal theory, Poisson processes, continuous-time Markov chains,  Brownian motion, and random walks. Here's one of the exercises: https://i.imgur.com/96o6fx7.png

Comment: @Math1000 ah thanks ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial sums of $\sum X_k$ are bounded by constant $c$ iff $|M_r|\le c$ for every $r$. This last occurs iff $T_c=\infty$ (where I write $T_c$ instead of $T$ to make the dependence on $c$ explicit). Therefore
$$
\{\text{partial sums of $\sum X_k$ are bounded}\} = \bigcup_{c=1}^\infty \{T_c=\infty\}.\tag1
$$
So if the LHS has positive probability then $P(T_c=\infty)>0$ for at least one $c$ (else the LHS has prob zero). Now continue with the rest of the proof of (b).

The Remark shows that we can relax the requirement that $\sum X_k$ converges a.s. to the stated assumption on the partial sums.

Comment: grand_chat, does the book have a typo? i'm not quite sure i follow otherwise. if $\sum X_k$ is convergent, then its partial sums are bounded, then we have $\sum \sigma_k^2 < \infty$. so we actually don't need to show $\sum X_k$ is convergent to get $\sum \sigma_k^2 < \infty$. we can show the weaker condition namely that partial sums are bounded. but how does the remark show that? i think the remark is supposed to show the converse instead

Comment: The condition "partial sums of $\sum X_k$ are bounded" is being evaluated pointwise, and is not (yet) known to hold a.s., so $\sum \sigma_k^2<\infty$ doesn't follow automatically. So $\sum\sigma_k^2<\infty$ still needs to be proven. You can imagine a sequence of zero-mean, uniformly bounded RVs where the partial sums are bounded only half the time, and are unbounded the rest of the time. The proof shows that requiring independence on the RVs will rule out that possibility.

Comment: so the conclusion of remark is a typo? It's supposed to conclude with $\sum \sigma_k^2 < \infty$?

Comment: Not really. Once you've concluded that $\sum\sigma_k^2<\infty$, you can then invoke part (a).

Comment: oh shoot I missed the positive probability vs almost sure thing. Thanks ^-^